# Penetration-resistance of a HaLVM unikernel

Tags: operating-systems, virtualization, kernel, runtime

A HaLVM unikernel is a Haskell program compiled with a modified version of the Glasgow Haskell Compiler to produce a standalone Xen kernel, which will boot on any Xen [PV](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Software_Overview#PV) machine instance. A HaLVM unikernel thus replaces the operating system with the runtime system provided by the Glasgow Haskell Compiler and a Haskell network stack.

The HaLVM-GHC compiler is a modification of the standard Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC), such that this compiler's runtime system (RTS) -- including memory allocator/manager, thread scheduler (and probably other parts) -- replace those functions of an operating system, and the [`hans`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hans) package provides a pure Haskell network stack.

Based on my understanding of all the things involved, I sense that the security of this constellation is either really high, or there are a couple a few obvious-to-any-pen-tester vulnerabilities that haven't been discovered yet, because the GHC RTS hasn't really been looked at from a software security perspective.

- Are there any demonstrations (with code examples) of a Haskell program taking control of the RTS from within?
- The RTS consists of (as per 2011) ~[50,000 lines of C code](http://www.aosabook.org/en/ghc.html). Has this been analyzed from a software security perspective?
- As a security guy, what is your personal sense of the security level of this stack (Haskell program <-> HaLVM unikernel <-> Xen PV <-> (Amazon Xen PV implementation?))?

It should be noted that [HaLVM uses GHC's single-threaded runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14341862/700597). How much of the 50,000 lines of C have to do with the multi-threaded runtime, thus making it irrelevant to the current version of HaLVM, I don't know. But in the future, HaLVM may support the multi-threaded runtime, and at least then will this portion of the RTS C code also be interesting from a security perspective.

**EDIT:** Turns out I was not paranoid when I included Amazon's Xen implementation as a risk factor: http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/08/new-attack-steals-private-crypto-keys-by-corrupting-data-in-computer-memory/. Looks like this is hardware-level stuff, but highly relevant nonetheless.

Comment: Assuming that only one program (functional part / process) runs on single HaLVM then out of just this the security is pretty much high. Another thing is how this instance would communicate with other instances. The high security and proper cryptography protocol would be something good as in Amazon it would involve networking.

Comment: What could be good would be to add something like trusted execution. So only trusted, signed code can be run for example at given network address. This is more difficult problem and I have no idea how this could be done with HaLVM.